# PTIJ - טו טו - Comparing Succos to Pesach

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In regards to the gezeiras shaveh from succos to pesach, what other dinim do we learn? Is one required to be יושב בסוכה on his left side? How much does it have to rain on pesach to make you patur from eating matzah - just a drop, as that would make it gebruchts, and ruin it? Or is it just a מנהג לחומרה?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I'm afraid you've got the _gezeirah shavah_ wrong. It's actually comparing Sukkot to Rosh HaShanah, where we hear the טו טו טו of the _shofar_.

Comment: I'm completely missing the humor here. What's the relevance to טו טו ? Where I sthis coming from / where is this idea mentioned?

Comment: @DanF Sukkah 27a has a gezeirah shavah between the first day of Pesach (15th) and first day of Sukkot (15th) to teach that one must eat in the sukkah on the first night of Sukkot, like one must eat matzah on the first night of Pesach. (The rest of Sukkot is optional - if one chooses to eat only potatoes one will not have to eat in the sukkah.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both we have the custom of inviting invisible guests. Arguably Sukkot is more outrageous because we invite (and pretend we will feed) not one but seven different individuals. But only on Pesach do we not only open the door and [pull](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Eating_in_the_Sukkah#Ushpizin) up a [chair](http://www.chabadluzern.com/templates/blog/post_cdo/aid/1320132/PostID/22344), but also pour a cup for our exalted friend to drink  -- all before relying on him to [make halachic rulings](https://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/tzarich-iyun/eliyahu-hanavi-seder/) for the seder.

We not only tell our children this when they ask, but fervently hope they will believe in it for their whole lives.

Comment: Isn't that why we say full hallel every day of Sukkot (as opposed to Peasach)?   You need "Panim Chadashot".

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of connections in fact.

One of the reasons that we sit in booths is to commemorate how Hashem protected us while we traveled in the desert, which is why Hashem allowed us to bring dough -- because he liked us. As the pasuk says, מצה חן במדבר

Also, the last day of Pesach commemorates Kri'at Yam Suf. We learn that the last day of the Sukkot holiday is its own holiday, of Atzeret, because, in the same way, the last day is called an end: "Kri'at yom, sof."

Answer (score 2):

They're both times when we eat lots of food, but they come with special diets - pesach food can't have starch from grains, and on succos you have to put on your coat and gloves and go outside to eat anything with starch.

Comment: Neither claim is true, you know. Corn starch is *kitniyot* - maybe. Even for Ashkenazim that don't eat *kitniyot*, some are lenient re kitniyot derivatives. And, matzot have plenty of starch, too. Re Succot - forget about what occurs in Florida during Succot. The past few years in the Northeast area have been stifling, as well.

Comment: that's why I said grains, but yeah. Still, it definitely minimizes the snacking

Comment: Corn, as well as just about every form of *kitniyot*, are grains. That's how the concern arose. The only items I can think of that are kitniyot but not grains are legumes, of which, peanuts are included.

Comment: I was using grain as in Chazal's definition, but OK

Answer (score 1):

A similar drasha is actually the reason for what many people mistakenly believe is a new minhag. The gemara connects Pesach with Tu BiShvat via the gezeira shaveh of טו טו and learns that just like we have a seder on Pesach, so too must we have a seder on Tu BiShvat.

Answer (score 1):

One halacha learned from the גזירה שוה is that on both holidays we should do things that hurt us in some way.

Building the Succah tends to cause back or neck pain from lifting heavy boards or stretching the wrong way to put up schach. It also causes sprained or bruised thumbs from hammering nails. If you're lucky enough not to get pain from that, the lulav inevitably pokes you in a finger or your back or somewhere else that isn't pretty.

On Pesach, we eat horseradish that hurts the tongue and throat. Then, there's an abundance of matzah as well as loads of other food that hurts the stomach.

Just remember that all that pain is done for the sake of praising G-d for the gift of these holidays so that we can eat a lot and gain weight. Remember - there's no gain without pain!

Comment: No chrein, no gain! And if you haven't injured yourself in Pesach cleaning, you haven't cleaned. (just kidding! haha)